# DRF can't filter anything

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to use filtersets in DRF. But nothing is working : my query params are ignored. And when I force them from navigation bar, nothing appends too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJVlT.png)

I 've tried with ModelViewSet and ListAPIView, and that fails again and again. It's like my DjangoFilterBackend is ignored... Here is my code :

```
class Ser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Project
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class Fil(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Project
        fields = ['id', 'name']
        # fields = {'id': ['in',], 'name': ['iexact',]} # not working too

class SomeListing(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Ser
    queryset = models.Project.objects.all()
    filterset_class : Fil

urlpatterns += path(f"{settings.API_URL_PREFIX}fii/", SomeListing.as_view(), name="fii-list"),
```

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':(
            'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
            "rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter",
        ),
        "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
        "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
        "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS,
        "PAGE_SIZE": 20,
    }
```

What the hell is wrong with my desing ?

Comment: filterset_class : Fil is just a type hint instead of assignment, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice....
But I remember use cases where I did a "=" assignment and it didn't work too.
I will try tomorrow to check that point
thx

Answer (score 0):

Your custom filter seems a bit weird. Maybe try starting with the simplest way: use the defaults.

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    ...
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
            'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
            "rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter",
    ],
}
```

view setup:

```
from core.models import Pizza
from recipes.serializers import PizzaSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['price', 'name', 'chef', 'toppings']
```

This enables basic stuff by filtering exact values. For something fancier, create a filterset. This is pretty much copied from [django_filter docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class), enabling min_price, max_price filtering:

```
from core.models import Pizza
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from recipes.serializers import PizzaSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    # enables ?min_price=
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    # enables ?max_price=
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = ['price', 'name', 'chef', 'toppings']


class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```